# How to migrate / backup & restore ink smart contract storage?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, storage, nodes, migration

Is there a way to backup ink smart contract `storage` and later restore on another chain? Lets say we have chain with `3 validators` and deployed smart contract containing certain information in its storage.

Next we setup a `larger chain with 300 validators`. How can we `migrate smart contracts storage` to this newer chain ?